# Adding an image to react-google-maps InfoWindow content

Tags: image, google-maps, infowindow, react-google-maps

Note: I am using the "react-google-maps" api and this is how my current InfoWindow is set up

```html
{showingInfoWindow && selectedPlace === spot._id && <InfoWindow
            className="info-window"
            onCloseClick={onInfoWindowClose}
            position={{lat: spot.lat, lng: spot.lng}}
            >
              <div className="iw-container">       
                <strong className="iw-title">{spot.name}</strong>
                <div className="iw-content">
                <a href={'https://maps.google.com/?ll=' + spot.lat + ',' + spot.lng} target= "_blank" className="iw-subTitle">{spot.location}</a>
                  <div>Added By: {currentUser.displayName === spot.user ? "Me" : spot.user}</div>
                  <div>{spot.type}</div>
                  <div>{spot.desc}</div>
                  <div>{moment(spot.createdAt).format("MMM Do YYYY")}</div>
                  {/* <img src={`/server/uploads/${spot.createdAt.split('.')[0]+"Z"}.jpg`}> </img> */}
                </div>
              </div>
              </InfoWindow>}
```

I was wondering how I add an image to the infowindow, I've seen it done with a content prop in other api's, and react-google-maps docs has a prop for updating the content, but I can't find how to set the content on their documentation. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: I needed to use a self-closing img tag.

instead of

```
<img src="..."> </img>
```

it must be

```
<img src="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add an `<img>` tag as a child of the `<infowindow>`

[Sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-n7m2rt?file=Map.js) snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from 'react-google-maps';


class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  handleToggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: true
    });
  };

  handleToggleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat:  -33.86882, lng: 151.209296 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
      >
        <Marker
          key={this.props.index}
          position={{  lat:  -33.86882, lng: 151.209296 }}
          onClick={() => this.handleToggleOpen()}
        >
          {this.state.isOpen && (
            <InfoWindow
              onCloseClick={this.props.handleCloseCall}
            >
             <img src="https://www.australia.com/content/australia/en/places/sydney-and-surrounds/guide-to-sydney/jcr:content/mainParsys/imagecontainer/imageContainerParsys/imagehighlights_835593945/ImageTile/imageHighlightsSrc.adapt.740.medium.jpg" width="250px" height="250px"/>
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </Marker>
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: when I use an img tag as a child I get this error: ×
Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code?